# using npm elastic-search in meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor, elasticsearch

I am using elastic-search node module in meteor Following is my code snippet.

```
//client side
if(Meteor.isClient)
{
  Template.body.events({
    'keyup #pinCode': function(data) {
      //event.preventDefault();
              console.log($('#pinCode').val());
               Meteor.call('new_earch',$('#pinCode').val(),
                            function(error, result) {
                                                      if(error){
                                                             console.error(error)
                                                            }
                                                      else {
                                                              console.log(result)
                                                            }
                });
           }});
}
```

The above client code is calling following server method:

```
//server side
var elasticsearch = Npm.require('elasticsearch');

Meteor.methods({
    new_earch: function(data){


    var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
                          host: 'localhost:9200',
                          log: 'trace'
                    });

 client.search({
    index: 'myjdbc',
    q:data+"*"
    },
     function (resp) {
        var hits = resp;
           console.log('*******************************************');
         console.log(hits);
          return hits;
    });

  }

});
```

But i am getting **undefined** value at client side. Whats the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed elasticsearch module globally?

https://gentlenode.com/journal/meteor-17-using-npm-modules-in-your-application/36

---

(update) try this:

```
result = client.search({
  index: 'myjdbc',
  q:data+"*"
});

return result.hits.hits.map(function(doc) {
  return doc._source;
});
```

---

(update #2)

The problem is because Meteor use Fibers. You can try something like this to make elasticsearch work with fibers:

```
//Example to work with
var Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');

var future = new Future();
// es client - https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticsearch
esClient.search({
  index: 'searchable-collection',
  q: q, // querystring
  size: 10, // 10 results
  function (err, response) {
    // grab all the ids
    var hitIds = _.pluck(reponse.hits.hits, '_id');
    // find all of documents by id and publish them
    future.return(
      SearchableCollection.find({_id: {$in: hitIds}})
    );
  }
});
```

You get the idea? Try `future.return()`

Or you can try meteorhaks packages:

1. https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-async
2. https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm

ps: as for me I'm going to send data through http PUT request since I will using only one ES instance.

Comment: add more console.log For example in your function(resp) I would add console.log(this). Also you should check if elasticsearch client was created

Comment: Also make sure that your elasticsearch instance is running. http://localhost:9200

Comment: i can see the results for console.log(this) and search result on server console. But  i am stuck at returning server response to client ie: meteor.call()

Comment: Oh! By the way! In your code there is function(resp) but first param must be an errorr. Try function(err, resp) :D

Comment: Are you sure that mistaken arguments position wasn't an issue? I've implemented elasticsearch on client side (it's almost the same) and there I have `(err, response)`  But you had just `resp` which is `error` and that's why it was undefined.. because you didn't have an error.

Comment: i used `client.search({...}).then(function(){..}) //(promise)` format as specified in node client example.